# Is there anyway to cache Angular templates?

Tags: angularjs

I'm thinking about making a web app using Angular, however, my primary concern is with its template engine and performance on mobile. I'm wondering if there is a way to precompile the templates much like you can with Handlebars. Can this be done in Angular? If my concern is speed, should I start looking into a different framework?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`$templateCache`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache) service?

Comment: The $templateCache simply caches the HTML, not the logic that creates the DOM Nodes from the HTML.

Comment: what are you trying to offload? When angular compiles template once...will also be stored in $templateCache

Comment: @charliefl The parsing of the DOM/HTML into a javascript function.

Comment: don't understand what you mean, or what the higher level issue is. WHat bottlencks do you have? Or is this all just theoretical?

Comment: So, when you create a template in Angular, the template needs to be parsed and turned into a set of instructions. I don't have an actual use-case where a bottleneck might be found, but I want to reduce the amount of processing required on the client side to as little as possible, and pre-compiling all templates would be a huge load off, id assume.